# Input events in unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to have an input, for example mouse click, to trigger an event rather then having the update routine check to see if mouse button is being click. I'm unable to get my example below to function.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.Events;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class GameController : MonoBehaviour, IPointerClickHandler
{
    public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("OnPointClick Event");
            switch (eventData.button)
            {
            case PointerEventData.InputButton.Left:
                Debug.Log("leftClick Event");
                break;
            case PointerEventData.InputButton.Right:
                Debug.Log("rightClick Event");
                break;
            case PointerEventData.InputButton.Middle:
                Debug.Log("middleClick Event");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As a side question: Why don't you use the Input.GetButton method?

Answer (score 0):

When using IPointerClickHandler,

1. Did you remember to put a collider on that object?
2. Did you remember to, on your camera, Inspector panel, click to add a Physics Raycaster (2D or 3D as relevant)?